# PDF translating software

Tags: windows, linux, osx, pdf, ocr

I'm looking for a software which can convert PDF files from various European languages (mostly German, Latin and French) to English.

The text in the PDF files are in computer fonts, but apparently cannot be selected in the PDF reader.

It also contains LaTeX (Math) equations, which I don't want to alter. Some online converters I used before altered them into strange symbols and the text was also partially translated and not accurate.

The software can be run on Windows 10/Linux/Mac O.S. I don't know the general cost of these, but you can post your recommendations regardless.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A lot depends on the exact type of pdf content - some PDFs contain the text and rendering instructions but others contain a sequence of images that would require OCR first. Also note that I have yet to hear of 100% accurate translation software especially for technical fields which if formulae are present this almost certainly is.

Comment: @Izzy Although I use Windows, I have a spare system where I can install Mac/Linux too. If you have any recommendations for those, I'll be glad if you could help.

Comment: As I wrote, I have none. I don't even know if such a solution exists. You will have to wait if someone else finds a solution. Though I agree with the problems Steve mentioned, so there might not be a "perfect candidate".